# Cannot use IOException in AbstractAction

Tags: java, swing, export, ioexception

I have run into a curious issue. I need to export some text to a file as a result of pressing a button in a GUI. I cannot, however, apply an IOException to the actionPerformed method of the AbstractAction that is called by the event. I am at a loss as to how to get around this.

Here is the export class:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ExportRunner
{
  public static void exportToFile(ArrayList<Locker> list) throws IOException
  {

  }
}
```

And the AbstractAction extension:

```
class Export extends AbstractAction
{
  public Export()
  {
    super("Export");
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    ExportRunner.exportToFile(list);
  }
}
```

Comment: Generally, I supply a "error manager" whose responsibility it is, is to handle these type of situations. It's a basic interface with a method like `errorOccured`, usually allowing the call to pass back some kind of message as well as the exception.  Also, don't block the Event Dispatching Thread with long running tasks or block calls, such as IO ;)

Comment: Same as Gamb, I have little to no idea how Exceptions work. I just want to get around having an IOException requirement on the Export class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all are you sure you want to re throw the exception or maybe is better to handle it and/or show a message to the user?

### Option 1: re-throw the exception (ugly in my opinion):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   try{
      ExportRunner.exportToFile(list);
   } catch(IOException ioex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ioex);
    }
  }
```

### Option 2: catch and handle it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   try{
      ExportRunner.exportToFile(list);
   } catch(IOException ioex) {
      handleItOrShowMessageToUser(ioex);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Given that this is a simple, small program that exports a small text file, and that I don't feel like diving into the world of exceptions at the moment, I'm going with the top example. I suppose I'll figure out why it works eventually. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would normally pass in a "error handler" to the action class that would allow the delegation of the responsibility of dealing with showing/reporting the error to another part of the application...

Something like...

```
public interface ErrorListener {
    public void errorOccurred(String msg, Exception exp);
}
```

Then you could pass it to you action...

```
public class Export extends AbstractAction
{
    private ErrorListener errorHandler;
    public Export(ErrorListener errorHandler)
    {
        super("Export");
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try {
            ExportRunner.exportToFile(list);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            errorHandler.errorOccurred("Failed to export file", exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, somewhere, you need a implementation to handle the callback ;)

You might like to have a look at the [Exception trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information